# How to plot various data sets on the same scatter plot with the same colour bar

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, graph, scatter3d

I have 4 variables that i would like to plot, i have a dictionary containing all the data i need which give x,y,z and c data. I would like to plot the position of each data point using the position of x,y and z with the fourth variable coloured using the range of 0 to 1. I can create the plot with each dataset from the key of the dictionary added onto the plot but dont know how to add a colour bar to this.

this is the section of my code that is user for plotting:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.set_xlabel('X (m)')
ax.set_ylabel('Y (m)')
ax.set_zlabel('Z (m)')
ax.set_xlim(0,0.1)
ax.set_ylim(0,0.04)
ax.set_zlim(-0.02,0.04)
cmp = plt.cm.get_cmap('RdYlBu')


for i in range(1,len(coordinates)):
    x = coordinates[i,0]  
    y = coordinates[i,1]

    X = plot_data["x-" + str(x) + "-y" + str(y)][:,0]
    Y = plot_data["x-" + str(x) + "-y" + str(y)][:,1]
    Z = plot_data["x-" + str(x) + "-y" + str(y)][:,2]
    c = plot_data["x-" + str(x) + "-y" + str(y)][:,3] 

    ax.scatter(X,Y,Z,c=c,vmin=0,vmax=1,cmap=cmp)
fig.colorbar(ax)  
plt.show()
```

The code loops through my dictionary fine and produces a plot i am happy with when i remove:

fig.colorbar(ax)

when i include it, the plot falls apart, is there a way to implement a colour bar for all this data that is being plot seperately?

Comment: assign the scatter to a variable, use that as argument to colorbar. `scatter = ax.scatter(..); fig.colorbar(scatter)`